# How to make user input Google Sheet database only using by Web App Form and RESTRICT to input directly in Google Sheet?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm making web app form using Google Apps Script for database input in Google Sheet. But I want to make users so they can **only** use the form for data input and **prevent** them to directly input in Google Sheet *(because the Google Sheet has to be shared, and users can directly modify it)*

I'm guessing this can be done at the back end, so this is the gs.code of my apps script

```
var folderID = ""; 
var sheetName = ""; 

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}


function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
  try {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var fileUrl = "";
    var fileName = "";

    
    if (formObject.myFile.length > 0) {
      var blob = formObject.myFile;
      var file = folder.createFile(blob);
      file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.first_name);
      fileUrl = file.getUrl();
      fileName = file.getName();
    } else{
      fileUrl = "Record saved without a file";
    }

    
    sheet.appendRow([
      formObject.first_name,
      formObject.last_name,
      formObject.gender,
      formObject.dateOfBirth,
      formObject.email,
      formObject.phone,
      fileName,
      fileUrl,
      Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]);
    
    
    return fileUrl;
    
  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

I tried to find some references but didn't get any clear explanation on how to do this. I'll take any suggestions anyone can offer.

Comment: About your situation, I have 2 questions. 1. Can you provide your setting for Web Apps? So, what values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:` are? 2. About `because the Google Sheet has to be shared, and users can directly modify it`, do you want to avoid editing your Spreadsheet by users while you want to share it with users?

Comment: do you want to avoid editing your Spreadsheet by users while you want to share it with users?  -  Yes, that's correct

The current Web App setting as follow: 
1. Execute as:  myself (my account)
2. Access to app:  only me

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The current Web App setting as follow: 1. Execute as: myself (my account) 2. Access to app: only me`, in this case, only the owner of Web Apps can access Web Apps. In this case, only the owner of Web Apps can access Web Apps. About `do you want to avoid editing your Spreadsheet by users while you want to share it with users? - Yes, that's correct`, in this case, the users can edit the Spreadsheet because your spreadsheet is shared with the users as the editor. From this situation, I'm worried that your goal cannot be achieved with this condition.

Comment: If you want to achieve your goal, please don't share your Spreadsheet with users or share users as the reader. And also, please set your Web Apps as `Execute as: Me`, `Who has access to the app: Anyone with Google account` or `Anyone`. By this, your script can put the values into a Spreadsheet while the Spreadsheet cannot be edited.

Comment: I see know, I think this is what I'm looking for: **Execute as: Me, Who has access to the app: Anyone with Google account**. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I thought that your question and the approach to the answer might be useful for other users. So, I posted it by summarizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your reply, your situation is as follows.

> - The current Web App setting as follow: 1. Execute as: myself (my account) 2. Access to app: only me

> - do you want to avoid editing your Spreadsheet by users while you want to share it with users? - Yes, that's correct

In this case, your Web Apps can be accessed by only the owner of the Web Apps. And, your Spreadsheet is shared with other users as the editor. I thought that this might not be your expected situation.

In order to achieve your goal that you want to make users put the values to your Spreadsheet using the HTML form, while your Spreadsheet is not shared with users, please do the following flow.

1. Please set your Web Apps as one of the following settings. By this setting, the script of Web Apps is run as the owner of Web Apps even when other users access your Web Apps.

   - `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone with Google account`

     - In this case, the user is required to log in to Google account.
   - `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`

     - In this case, the user is not required to log in to Google account.
2. When you set the above setting to your Web Apps, your Spreadsheet is not required to be shared with the users.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)